# Unable to identify the webelement in Android6.x versions in APPIUM

Tags: javascript, appium

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k5sWx.png)I have written automation test scripts for my native app for Android platform.
I use `UIAutomatorViewer` to identify the elements.
But the scripts fail to identify the elements on Android6.x .

I have tried using the following

1. `@FindBy(id ="com.husqvarna.connect:id/toolbar_title")` in my page object model pages.
2. `driver.findElementById("com.husqvarna.connect:id/toolbar_title")`.
3. `driver.findElementByXPath("//android.view.ViewGroup[@index='0']/android.widget.LinearLayout[@index='0']/android.widget.FrameLayout[@index='0']/android.widget.LinearLayout[@index='0']/android.view.ViewGroup[@index='0']/android.widget.RelativeLayout[@index='1']/android.widget.TextView[@index='0']")`
4. `driver.findElement(By.xpath("/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FramerLayout/android.view.ViewGroup[@index='0']/android.widget.LinearLayout[@index='0']/android.widget.FrameLayout[@index='0']/android.widget.LinearLayout[@index='0']/android.view.ViewGroup[@index='0']/android.widget.RelativeLayout[@index='1']/android.widget.TextView[@index='0']")).getText();`

[image]

Comment: What's the Appium version that you use? Also can you please share the Appium error log?

Comment: @AnishPillai  I am using  Appium v1.6.5.. error log is:

Comment: Does it happen with all the controls? Maybe there's some webview or something due to which some controls are not getting identified? Is it possible for you to try this on some other device as well? It sometimes can be device specific issue also.

Comment: @AnishPillai i tried with the different device and it is working fine now.. Thank u.